# Tracking down display errors in IE, when everything looks good in firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, compatibility

I am a super newb at developing web pages. Especially pages that are created dynamically from javascript.

I have a page that I have worked on that uses some templates from prototype, and widgets from dojo, as well as plain old javascript. This page looks and acts perfectly in firefox.

It is basically adding rows to a table, and adding widgets to the cells.

The widgets basically seem like they are in the wrong column/wrong place.

Where do I start looking to figure out what the incompatibilities are between firefox and IE?

Comment: Noone can answer your question unless you provide better information -- both in quantity, and in quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: http://www.quirksmode.org/

I am currently trying to make a template that displays well with FF do the same in IE.

So far, I am breaking it down div by div with corresponding JS function.

Then it is easier to look up the specifics of that particular piece you are trying to make compatible.

For example, I was implementing the enter key and noticed it worked well in FF and not IE. After I looked at that specific input box in html and gathered there were no problems with it, I dove into that specific JS function. Inside I found that the currentTarget wasn't "working". I did a [quick search on current target in IE](http://www.google.com/search?q=event+current+target+IE&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=wks&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&q=javascript+currenttarget+ie&aq=0m&aqi=g-m1g-v1g-sv1&aql=&oq=currenttarget+IE&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec) and got all the info I needed to get it to work.

Get yourself a good JS debugger as well, [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) works with both browsers.

There just aren't good web standards in the web industry right now. Everyone is doing their own thing, it is like the house and bank market. [These guys are trying though](http://www.webstandards.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of sites that will give you information about compatibility. I'd check google. Also, you can download [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which will allow you to see how your site looks in most IE versions (5.5+).